# How to Extract HTML from Content Fetched with Ajax using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page, in which there are a couple of Option elements whose Value point to external pages. My aim is to use Ajax to extract the chosen Option's Value & use that to load content from external pages. E.g. When a user chooses Volleyball, I will get the 'volleyball.html' value, use Ajax to retrieve that page and load its #catalog content into the current page. Here's my code:

```
$("select").change(function(){
var selectedURL=$("option:selected",this).val();
if(selectedURL!=="Select One"){
    $("#center").html("<p class='processing'></p>");    
    $.get(selectedURL,function(data){
    var extractedContent=$("#catalog",data);
    console.log(extractedContent); //Firebug says extractedContent is '[]'
    $("#center").html(extractedContent); //Nothing is inserted inside div#content
    },"html");
}
```

I'm not good at jQuery, and have kind of mixed and matched code from a few posts here to derive at the above. Now I'm not sure what went wrong, but nothing is loaded - the #center div block that is supposed to hold the extracted content is empty.

Can someone please help me spot just what's wrong with my code above? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your help. However, it seems that only niftydude's suggested code works. Both powerbuoy and corneliu's code outputs the entire html instead of just #catalog's contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `load()` method is perfect for this:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var selectedURL = $('option:selected', this).val();

    if (selectedURL !== 'Select One') {
        $('#center').html('<p class="processing"></p>').load(selectedURL + ' #catalog');
    }
});
```

It can take only a URL, *or* it can take a URL followed by a selector which will only load the contents of the matched element (`#catalog`) into the element it is called on (`#center`).

Comment: Hey @powerbuoy, thanks for your help. However, I tested it out and it seems that adding a + sign followed by the id of the content like you suggested achieves the same effect as just extracting the entire html, so it didn't work for me.

Comment: Hmm, did you make sure to put a space between the URL and the selector? It should be: `load('url selector')`.

Comment: I tried `.load(selectedURL "#catalog")` - Firebugs complains: 'missing ) after argument list'. I also tried `.load(selectedURL + "#catalog")`, but as I said, it retrieves everything. I even tried `.load("selectedURL + #catalog")` and `.load("selectedURL + '#catalog'")` - both couldn't load anything. I know we can use load('test.php #id'), but in my case I'm not using an explicit URL but selectedURL, that's why I'm having problems.

Comment: It should be: `.load(selectedURL + ' #catalog')`. Notice the space (' ') before `#catalog`. It is required so that `load()` understands that the string passed in is both a URL _and_ a selector. Edit: `.load(selectedURL "#catalog")` is a syntax error, `.load("selectedURL + #catalog")` literally tries to load the string "selectedURL + #catalog" and `.load(selectedURL + '#catalog')` (no space before #catalog) would try to load something like `/some/url/#catalog` which isn't correct either.

Comment: Now I see. Didn't notice the space earlier. What a difference a space makes. Thanks for the clear explanation man!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").change(function(){
    var selectedURL=$("option:selected",this).val();
    if(selectedURL!=="Select One"){
        $("#center").html("<p class='processing'></p>");    
        $.get(selectedURL,function(data){
            $("#center").html($(data).find("#catalog"));
        },"html");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, it didn't work though - it effectively extracts the entire html instead of just #catalog. Also, you might wanna know that your above $("#center").html($(data).find("#catalog")) didn't run - it has to be $("#center").html($(data)).find("#catalog"); instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `$('#catalog', data)` just like that. To extract content, you can create a jQuery object, and assign the HTML returned then extract from there:

```
var extractedContent = $('<div />').html(data).find('#catalog').html();
console.log(extractedContent);
$("#center").html(extractedContent);
```

Comment: Hey @niftydude, thanks - your code works perfectly.:) By the way, if I take out the last 'html' parameter from the $.get function, I notice that even your code fails, with the error 'Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy'. Any idea why that's so?

Comment: Hmm, not sure why it fails, as the default of that last argument is actually 'html', could you show your code without the last argument?

Comment: As I understand it, the last argument is optional, isn't it? anyway, I just wanna know why we have to put in the last argument as 'html'. Never mind. Anyway, here's the failed code: `if(selectedURL!=="Select One"){
      $("center").html("<p class='processing'></p>");
      $.get(selectedURL,function(data){
      var extractedContent=$("<div />").html(data).html();
      console.log(extractedContent);
         $("#center").html(extractedContent);
     });
         }`

Comment: @anthonyteo yes it is optional, and defaults to 'html', was my point :) ok let me see give me a second

Comment: @anthonyteo Actually from the docs at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/, it says that the fourth argument is "Intelligent Guess", so I think it's safest if you explicitly set it to 'html'

Comment: Strange. Wonder what jQuery guessed it was instead of html. Probably xml or something. Anyway thanks a lot for your help man.